# In Windows is any folder alternative to ProgramData?

Tags: windows, desktop, configuration-files

I'm writing a desktop app and need a folder which...

- Exists in Windows 7 and Vista
- Is common to all users (for store config data).
- Application can save data on it, without Admin privileges (not like "ProgramData").
- is standard (I don't want to create another app specific folder in "C:", the Desktop or other place alike.)
- "Program Files" is not an option, of course.

Can you suggest an appropriate folder, or better use the Registry?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The recommended way to do this is to create a folder at install time, dedicated to your application, underneath "ProgramData" (i.e. `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA`/`FOLDERID_ProgramData`).

As you already know, the `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` folder is read only for standard users. So  your install program needs to give the folder that it creates an ACL that permits the access that you require.

This is the solution that meets all the criteria laid out in your bullet points.

You mention the registry. There is no area of the registry that is shared between all users and yet writeable by standard users. Whilst you can use ACLs to grant more permissive access rights to the registry, it is really not the done thing. Please forget that I even mentioned this possibility!

Answer (score 2):

IF your app is .NET then use [`CommonApplicationData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) - you can get the real location by calling [`GetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx).

EDIT - as per comments:

You need to setup ACL correctly - for sample source code on how to do this see http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/61987/Allow-write-modify-access-to-CommonApplicationData

Comment: IIRC the default ACL for it is to be read-only for regular users (but I may be wrong), so you should grant explicitly to everyone write access in your subfolder during installation (as specified by @DavidHeffernan).

Comment: `CommonApplicationData` is the same thing as "ProgramData", CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, FOLDERID_ProgramData.

Comment: @MatteoItalia you are right... updated the answer with a link to sample source on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

What about Public User directories? For Example: `C:\Users\Public\Libraries` or `C:\Users\Public\Documents`

I've noticed these folder on several of my Windows 7 machines. I'm not sure if it is always there, but might be an option. I was hoping for something like an `%appdata%` for the Public User, but the closest thing I found was `Public\Libraries`.

(As a side note, it appears `C:\Users\Public\Desktop` does require admin to write to.)

Answer (score 0):

what about using %APPDATA%/Company/Product for the directory?